# control font and character set in console using visual studio c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, console

Every time I run debugger debugging console shows it's "prefered" font "lucida console" instead of "console" ... and always ignores diacritics from any european language   characters over 0x7f are considered graphics or so... 
So I ask How to select Font used in Console, type and size.
I ask too, what header file or instruction should I use to have 
std::cout << "...  ácido propiónico  como fungicida ... y sus sales de amoníaco ... " be written with teese special á ó  í  or others like ñ Ç deustche dzet ...

Sorry maybe those  questions  need to be asked elsewhere ... I would be pleased to learn where and how ...
thanks

Answer (score 0):

[`SetCurrentConsoleFontEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setcurrentconsolefontex) would be my starting point.

Note the font selection is by index, and these are defined in the registry:

```
 Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Console\TrueTypeFont
```

Note: the names needs to be a sequence of "0" and the value is the font name.

**But** you would be better off just setting the console properties for that Window: they are retained per executable: open the system menu of the console window and modify its properties.

Comment: yes   tha's I did untill now, change every time I need it, because sometimes Lucida Console dosn't matter...   the page code is more annoying because I wrote small applications to implement things that ppl use to do    but writing spanish without accents looks like poor, not to say that the country itself has an ñ in the name